# How to detect the network connection in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript1.8

I am trying to detect my wifi connection is connected or not with the help of [this website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/). I have tried:

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) {

  }

  obtainNetworkConnection() {
    console.log("hello");

    // watch network for a disconnect
    let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    });

    // stop disconnect watch
    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();


    // watch network for a connection
    let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');     
      // We just got a connection but we need to wait briefly
       // before we determine the connection type.  Might need to wait     
      // prior to doing any api requests as well.
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (Network.connection === 'wifi') {
          console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });

    // stop connect watch
    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

my .html

```
<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <button (click)="obtainNetworkConnection()" full>Get Nettwork Connection</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Emm.. you put your code in the class body, don't do that :)

Comment: Put it into method or I guess you need to put it in constructor

Comment: so what is the formate help me i am getting error on this line `let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {`

Comment: Class has methods, it is not a function. Just put this code into constructor block

Comment: yes thanks i did not get any error now but ...!!! how to call my constructor in from UI so that i can get to print my console.log

Comment: You better to read about classes.https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: i have updated my code with a function and i tried to call that function from you i just gave console.log("hello world ") printed but i am not able to get printed my connection details do you have any idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120998/discussion-between-frione-and-mohan-gopi).

Comment: this [link](http://blog.ionic.io/building-an-ionic-app-with-offline-support-part-2/) will help

Comment: @Jagannath good one thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late answer, but added only relevant code and link for quick reference purpose.

> The Actual problem in the question, the constructor parameters was
>   missing the Network dependency.

[Network Plug In Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/)

[Platform Plug In Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/)

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private network: Network, private platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
       let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
           console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
       });

       // stop disconnect watch
       disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();

      // watch network for a connection
      let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
          console.log('network connected!');
      });
    });

    // stop connect watch
    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Hope this answer helps to someone in the future! :)

Comment: This solution can be used to track the changes in the network connection. Is there any other method to check connection status while initial loading of the app

Comment: @sumitmehra Did you get the answer? I am also having the same question.